# I don't know what Rtools path should be

Tags: r, directory, path, package, rtools

What should I write on ${PATH}?
First, I thought it was the directory where the script I was working on.
Second I thought it was the directory where the make or something is.
But both were wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`${PATH}` is the value of the path variable already present on your computer.

`PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"` is adding `${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin` to the existing path so that RTOOLS can be found when needed.

If RTOOLS installation went correctly, `RTOOLS40_HOME` environment variable should have automatically been set up to the directory where RTOOLS is installed.

Comment: So if rtools is installed in C:/rtools, PATH="$C:/rtools/usr/bin;$C:/rtools"?

Comment: if you do so, you might overwrite path set by other programs. Under Windows, you can check content of path & RTOOLS40_HOME with command line : echo %PATH% or echo %RTOOLS40_HOME%.